# kotlin sqlite create two tables

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

We are trying to create two tables in a DB with Kotlin. We have tried multiple various syntax. If we comment out all the code associated with the second table the  first table is created and holds data. Here is the relevant code

```
class DBHelper(context: Context):SQLiteOpenHelper(context,DBHelper.DB_NAME,null,DBHelper.DB_VERSION) {

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

    val CREATE_TABLE_DEPT = "CREATE TABLE ${DEPT_TABLE} ($colidD INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colDept TEXT);"
    val CREATE_TABLE_ITEM = "CREATE TABLE ${ITEM_TABLE} ($colidI INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colItem TEXT);"
    db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DEPT + CREATE_TABLE_ITEM)
    //db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEM)
}


override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    val DROP_TABLE_DEPT = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $DEPT_TABLE"
    val DROP_TABLE_ITEM = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $ITEM_TABLE"
    db!!.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_DEPT + DROP_TABLE_ITEM)
    //db!!.execSQL(DROP_TABLE_ITEM)
    onCreate(db)
}
```

Companion object

```
    companion object {
    private val DB_VERSION = 1
    private val DB_NAME = "Grocery.db"
    private val DEPT_TABLE = "Deptatment"
    private val colidD = "idD"
    private val colDept = "Dept"
    private val ITEM_TABLE = "GroceryItems"
    private val colidI = "idI"
    private val colItem = "Item"
}
```

We hope the question is obvious! How to create a second table in sqlite with Kotlin?

Comment: @VirRajpurohit Worked Great We knew that + sign was a stretch One Note for others if you try to open the db file with DB Browser you need to put db-wal and db-shu files with the db or DB Browser tells you nothing NOT sure where these two file came from ? ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DEPT + CREATE_TABLE_ITEM)` was wrong.
Try

```
db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DEPT ); db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEM);
```

Comment: We did this the issue was we never need the addition db-wal and db-shu files to view the db with DB Browser Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

No matter you are using Android or kotlin.

You should define your code as below.

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

    val CREATE_TABLE_DEPT = "CREATE TABLE ${DEPT_TABLE} ($colidD INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colDept TEXT);"
    val CREATE_TABLE_ITEM = "CREATE TABLE ${ITEM_TABLE} ($colidI INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colItem TEXT);"

    db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DEPT)
    db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEM)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate your SQl queries. Instead write queries in different statements. For eg;

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

        val CREATE_TABLE_DEPT = "CREATE TABLE if not exists ${DEPT_TABLE} ($colidD INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colDept TEXT);"
        val CREATE_TABLE_ITEM = "CREATE TABLE if not exists ${ITEM_TABLE} ($colidI INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $colItem TEXT);"
        db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DEPT )
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEM)
        //db!!.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEM)
    }
```